# Performance degradation after moving to jersey 2

Tags: java, spring, jersey-2.0

We're working on a server using spring 4, embedded jetty 9 and jersey. Recently, we moved to jersey 2.13 and we noticed a degradation in performance. I performed some investigations using YourKit. I saw that there is a massive CPU usage in reflection done by jersey. Also, there are many `NoSuchMethodExceptions` and `ClassNotFoundExceptions` in Yourkit snapshot.

[image]

Are there any jersey configuration or a best practice to avoid this issue, or to optimize jersey? Or maybe it is a known issue in jersey 2?

Here are two screenshots from YourKit, showing the hot-spots, after excluding the socket read (`java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0`). The first one is with Merged Callees:

[image]

And the second one is with Back Trace:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You're just looking at blind statistics, numbers - at this point in time: lies in the making. What is interesting is where those exceptions are coming from. Then at least you know what to blame rather than just pointing the finger at "jersey 2". More likely it is one of the object mapping technologies that is configured. Dig deeper, don't stop at the first sign of trouble.

Comment: You are right. i didn't show you the whole picture. I edited the question and I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: could be good to publicate your code in git (web.xml, app.java) at least in order to see your config. We are blind as it, to help you.

Comment: Hello, in my opinion the no such method exception is comming from dependency problems. Some packages only declare interfaces and your webapp relies thath an implementation is present at runtime. Changing the version of jersey (which is the implementation) probably implies changing the version of other related dependencies. Please check your POM

Comment: Have you been running for some time? Otherwise chances are that you are looking at startup deployment statistics. Also, why don't you enable instrumentation so you get call counts? That will probably help you see what is done per request and what is done once only.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your question I can not pin point the exact issue. But I can suggest you to check the following things:

1. Check if there are any duplicate libraries/jars with different versions in your final build
2. Check whether you have recommended Spring/jersey transitive dependency/jar versions in your final build

If you are using maven to build your project, then I suggest using the maven dependency tree plugin to check the above mentioned points.

-
Chiru