# Multiple @Path's in JAX-RS

Tags: java, spring, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Background: I asked another question (here: [Performance degradation after moving to jersey 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27396097/performance-degradation-after-moving-to-jersey-2)) about jersey performance. I also opened an issue in jersey Jira. Apparently, there is a known performance problem with sub-resources in jersey 2.

My data model based on entity A, with several sub-entities. However, the ID of the sub entities is unique, and the server allows to access them directly. For example,

/server/As/{a_id}/Bs/{b_id} == /server/Bs/{b_id}

We're using sub-resources for that, so the same resource (B) is both a spring component and a member of A resource. All the resources are spring beans, so both Bs are the same instance.

Now I'm trying to workaround this problem by not using sub-resources at all. I found out that @Path does not support multiple paths. Is there any idea how to solve it?

I tried the following, does it make sense? Can you offer alternatives? I'm asking because I'll have to do the same trick many times (for entities C, D, E etc. and maybe additional level of resources)

First, I removed B reference from A resource class, then:

```
public abstract class AbstractB {

    @GET
    @Path({b_id})
    @Produce(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getB(@PathParam("b_id") String bId) {
        ...
    } 

    ...
}

@Component
@Path ("As/{a_id}/Bs") 
public class B extends AbstractB{/* empty */}

@Component
@Path ("Bs") 
public class AsB extends AbstractB{/* empty */}
```

---

**Edit:** (by peeskillet) - [**Link to issue**](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2727?jql=project%20%3D%20JERSEY%20AND%20created%3E%3D-1w%20ORDER%20BY%20created%20DESC)

Comment: Can you use a delegate instead? if you can inject the class that has the BL for B, you can just call the same REST endpoint from there.